# Whether the below matrices are in row-echelon form / reduced row-echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to ask whether the following matrix is a row echelon matrix (and reduced row-echelon matrix). 
The below are $1 \times 1$ matrices. 
(a) $\begin{pmatrix} 0\end{pmatrix}$ 
(b) $\begin{pmatrix} 1\end{pmatrix}$ 
(c) $\begin{pmatrix} 2\end{pmatrix}$

The below are $n\times1$ matrices, where $n\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \geq 2$ 
(d) $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Here are my opinions. I would like for my opinions be confirmed (or to be countered if mine is wrong): 
(a) It is a row echelon form and reduced row echelon form. 
(b) It is a row echelon form and reduced row echelon form. The entry $1$ is the leading one. 
(c) It is a row echelon form, but it is not a reduced row echelon form, since there is no leading $1$ before $2$ 
(d) It is a row echelon form and reduced echelon form. \

(For (d), it is inspired by " [Is a $1 \times n$ matrix already in echelon form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494036/is-a-1-times-n-matrix-already-in-echelon-form) ".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **Linear Algebra and Its Applications** by Lay, p. 13

A rectangular matrix is in echelon form (or row echelon form) if it has the following three properties:

1. All nonzero rows are above any rows of all zeros.
2. Each leading entry of a row is in a column to the right of the leading entry of the row above it.
3. All entries in a column below a leading entry are zeros.

If a matrix in echelon form satisfies the following additional conditions, then it is in reduced echelon form (or reduced row echelon form):

4. The leading entry in each nonzero row is 1.
5. Each leading 1 is the only nonzero entry in its column.

A leading entry of a row refers to the leftmost nonzero entry (in a nonzero row).

So, yes you are correct based on the above.